# SAS not picking up years in loop

Tags: arrays, sas, do-loops, sas-studio

I am working with the following dataset

```
data have;
    input repricingdate1-repricingdate3;
    datalines;

    '30SEP2019'd '31DEC2020'd '31MAR2022'd
    '31DEC2020'd '30JUN2023'd '31DEC2025'd
    ;

run;
```

please excuse me if that's not the correct way to input dates, I'm unsure but I have a table with those values using an intnx function

I am looking to create a variable "Flag" which returns a '1' if the repricingdate matches the Flag year i.e. Flag(2019)=1 for the first line, Flag(2020)=1 for both lines and so on.

I am using the below code and can't see where my mistake lies, it even picks up a couple of rows in a larger dataset but is sporadic

```
data want;
    set have;

    array flag(2018:2021) flag2018-flag2021;
    array repricingdate(1:3);

    do i = 2018 to 2021;

        do j = 1 to 3;
            if put(repricingdate(j), 4.) = compress(vname(flag(i)),, 'kd') 
            then flag(i)=1;
        end;
    end;

    drop i;

run;
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your error is but you can drastically simplify this by finding the year and just setting those to 1 rather than looping through all.

```
data want;
    set have;

    array flag(2018:2021) flag2018-flag2021;
    array _date(1:3);

        *set all to 0 initially;
        do i=lbound(flag) to hbound(flag);
                flag(i)=0;
        end;

        do i = 1 to 3;
            year_data=year(_date(i));
            flag(year)=1;
        end;


    drop i;

run;
```

EDIT: 
Your error is here:
 `put(repricingdate(j), 4.)`  -> This does not generate a year value. 
If you want the year use the YEAR function instead
    `year(repricingdate(j))`

This assumes your dates are actually SAS dates. As you mentioned, your demo code

Comment: My error is that the flags aren't filling out with my second piece of code but I've managed to restructure it and get a solution.

I'll try this too.

Comment: I added what your issue is but didn't test, as you suggested, your example code does not run correctly. There is code here to create demo data: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-a-data-step-version-of-your-data-AKA-generate/ta-p/258712